# How to expand Navbar with Reactstrap

Tags: html, css, reactjs, reactstrap

i am new to working with Reactstrap. My Navbar Toggler isn't working and my Navbar isn' expanding and I don' know why. I think that i understood the logic behind it but i can't get it to work properly

//imports

```
import { * } from "reactstrap";
import React from "react";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
```

// Code

```
<Navbar color="light" fixed="top" light>
          <NavbarBrand href="/">reactstrap</NavbarBrand>
          <NavbarToggler onClick={function noRefCheck() {}} />
          <Collapse navbar>
            <Nav className="me-auto" navbar>
              <NavItem>
                <NavLink href="/components/">Components</NavLink>
              </NavItem>
              <NavItem>
                <NavLink href="https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap">
                  GitHub
                </NavLink>
              </NavItem>
              <UncontrolledDropdown inNavbar nav>
                <DropdownToggle caret nav>
                  Options
                </DropdownToggle>
                <DropdownMenu right>
                  <DropdownItem>Option 1</DropdownItem>
                  <DropdownItem>Option 2</DropdownItem>
                  <DropdownItem divider />
                  <DropdownItem>Reset</DropdownItem>
                </DropdownMenu>
              </UncontrolledDropdown>
            </Nav>
            <NavbarText>Simple Text</NavbarText>
          </Collapse>
        </Navbar>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using `Collapse` componet so, it need a prop called `isOpen` and need to update the value passed to `isOpen` when clicking on the `NavbarToggler`.

//Code

```
//imports
import { * } from "reactstrap";
import React from "react";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";

// Main Code
const functionName = () => {

  const [collapsed, setCollapsed] = useState(true);
  const toggleNavbar = () => setCollapsed(!collapsed);

  return(
    <Navbar color="light" fixed="top" light>
          <NavbarBrand href="/">reactstrap</NavbarBrand>
          <NavbarToggler onClick={toggleNavbar} />
          <Collapse navbar isOpen={!collapsed}>
            <Nav className="me-auto" navbar>
              <NavItem>
                <NavLink href="/components/">Components</NavLink>
              </NavItem>
              <NavItem>
                <NavLink href="https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap">
                  GitHub
                </NavLink>
              </NavItem>
              <UncontrolledDropdown inNavbar nav>
                <DropdownToggle caret nav>
                  Options
                </DropdownToggle>
                <DropdownMenu right>
                  <DropdownItem>Option 1</DropdownItem>
                  <DropdownItem>Option 2</DropdownItem>
                  <DropdownItem divider />
                  <DropdownItem>Reset</DropdownItem>
                </DropdownMenu>
              </UncontrolledDropdown>
            </Nav>
            <NavbarText>Simple Text</NavbarText>
          </Collapse>
        </Navbar>
    );
}
```

Use `expand={"lg"}` in Navbar tag so that if its bigger screen then it will expand fully and for smaller screen it be collapse.

Answer (score 0):

You cant use {*} for calling the reactstrap components. You need to call each components that you use in code.

This might help you out

```
import React from "react";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import {
  Collapse,
  Navbar,
  NavbarToggler,
  NavbarBrand,
  Nav,
  UncontrolledDropdown,
  DropdownToggle,
  DropdownMenu,
  DropdownItem,
  NavLink,
  NavItem,
  NavbarText
} from "reactstrap";

export default function Main() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar color="light" fixed="top" light expand={true}>
        <NavbarBrand href="/">reactstrap</NavbarBrand>
        <NavbarToggler onClick={function noRefCheck() {}} />
        <Collapse navbar>
          <Nav className="me-auto" navbar>
            <NavItem>
              <NavLink href="/components/">Components</NavLink>
            </NavItem>
            <NavItem>
              <NavLink href="https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap">
                GitHub
              </NavLink>
            </NavItem>
            <UncontrolledDropdown inNavbar nav>
              <DropdownToggle caret nav>
                Options
              </DropdownToggle>
              <DropdownMenu end>
                <DropdownItem>Option 1</DropdownItem>
                <DropdownItem>Option 2</DropdownItem>
                <DropdownItem divider />
                <DropdownItem>Reset</DropdownItem>
              </DropdownMenu>
            </UncontrolledDropdown>
          </Nav>
          <NavbarText>Simple Text</NavbarText>
        </Collapse>
      </Navbar>
    </div>
  );
}
```

you need to use `expand={true}` or use anyone in expand **sm,md, lg,xl, true, false** these are all you can call out as per requirement.
For `DropdownMenu` the `right` property has been **Deprecated** use `end` instead.
For more details you can visit the document page of reactstrap.

Comment: Hey, i just wrote a star to get rid of the warning that i posted too much code. ALso this code doesnt leave a taskbar with an active navbar toggler when its on fullscreen

Comment: You can see here its working. https://codesandbox.io/s/late-leftpad-ztnfok?file=/src/Main.js

Comment: nope isnt working in this preview: "Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop."

Comment: you can check again here https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-ritchie-k5k0lw?file=/src/Main.js

Comment: @AnsulAgrawal, I don't get it. Even your latest example, codesandbox.io/s/trusting-ritchie-k5k0lw?file=/src/Main.js, doesn't work.